# automatic inventoring of machines to glpi 10.0.5 installed on my server

Tags: glpi

I installed glpi on a server and I want to do automatic inventoring of other computers and machines in the park.
I tried to install FusionInventory but its last version isn't compatible with glpi 10.0.5.

Is there an other plugin that i can use please?

Answer (score 0):

GLPI from 10.x onwards now has its own agent that can be installed on clients. Details can be found here:
https://glpi-agent.readthedocs.io/en/latest/